# File changes when downloaded via curl

Tags: curl, nginx, artifactory

I have an artifactory instance running in private network in which I would like to keep vagrant boxes.

Problem I am having is that when box is downloaded by vagrant (curl in the end) the file seems to get changed when it actually reaches my machine. The `sha256sums` are always different, no matter how many times I try.

When I download the same file though the artifactory webpage, the `sha256sum` is correct and file is not changed.

Any idea what could cause this? Not nice to provide other people a box that they have to always manually download.

NOTE: My artifactory instance is behind Nginx proxy and nginx is listening for both port 80 and 442 TLS.

Comment: Did you try using the same URL as Vagrant is using for downloading the box? you can try downloading it from the same URL and inspect the box you are getting. From the info you provided it seems like an nginx configuration issue

Comment: The box looks the same but importing it into virtualbox fails with a VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED error. So the box has gotten corrupted I imagine.

Comment: In order to isolate the problem I suggest trying to resolve the box from Artifactory directly. If it work than the issue is probably an nginx one.